# How do I fix a botched brush on primer job

Tags: sanding, primer

My primer came out lumpy and I sanded it and it feels smooth but it looks uneven how do I fix it without sanding into the underlying material

Comment: What object or surface are we talking about here? Please revise to provide more information.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Primer doesn't necessarily need to look even, it's there for surface preparation (sealing and adhesion of topcoat) and bleedthrough prevention.

Unless you have a pretty extreme mistake or you're going for an extremely smooth finish like a bicycle or something else that's metal, most painted home surfaces (cabinets, walls, doors) have some texture from the nap of the rollers used to quickly paint large surfaces so smoothness isn't top priority there.

In any case, sanding out any lumps you may have should be enough, you can use another coat of primer if you're really concerned but primer often looks splotchy because it isn't designed to look good, as it's always coated by a top coat.

Comment: I’m about to prime it one more time because there are thin spots and thick spots although it feels smooth. I’m using a gloss black enamel over top of it so it’s probably going to show mistakes. Thank you for your prompt answer